# "IndexError: list index out of range" with elif statement

Tags: python

I have written a script that parses html code from certain websites to pull specific data. I have two different sites that I pull this data from, so I use an elif statement. Here is the code:

```
import urllib

class city :
    def __init__(self, city_name, link) :
            self.name = city_name
            self.url = link
            self.high0 = 0
            self.high1 = 0
            self.high2 = 0
            self.high3 = 0
            self.high4 = 0
            self.high5 = 0
            self.high6 = 0
            self.low0 = 0
            self.low1 = 0
            self.low2 = 0
            self.low3 = 0
            self.low4 = 0
            self.low5 = 0

    def retrieveTemps(self) :
            filehandle = urllib.urlopen(self.url)

            # get lines from result into array
            lines = filehandle.readlines()

            # (for each) loop through each line in lines
            line_number = 0 # a counter for line number
            for line in lines:
                    line_number = line_number + 1 # increment counter

# find string, position otherwise position is -1

                    position1 = line.rfind('#f2')
                    if position1 > 0 :
                            self.high0 = lines[line_number].split('&')[0].split('>')[1] # next line: high
                            self.low0 = lines[line_number + 10].split('&')[0].split('>')[1] # next line:low
                    elif position1 < 0 :
                            position1 = line.rfind('>Overnight')
                            if position1 > 0 :
                                    self.high0 = lines[line_number + 9].split('&')[0].split(':')[1] # next line: high
                                    self.low0 = lines[line_number + 15].split('&')[0].split(':')[1] # next line:low
```

The script works perfectly when position1 = line.rfind('#f2'). However, when it can't find '#f2' (this is only located in the html code of the first site, not the second), I am trying to tell it to look for '>Overnight' and then extract the data between the ':' and the '&'. The 'data' will always be a single number. I am thinking that one problem may be there is a space on either side of this number I am trying to extract, but I am not sure how to resolve this issue. When I run the script I get the error:

self.high0 = lines[line_number + 9].split('&')[0].split(':')[1] # next line: high
"IndexError: list index out of range"

For reference, here is the html code I am parsing for the first website:

```
</h3><img src="/weathericons/15.gif" longdesc="#f2" alt="Rain mixed with snow" title="Rain mixed with snow" /><ul>
              <li class="high" title="High">3&deg;C</li>
              <li class="low">&nbsp;</li>
              <li class="pop">&nbsp;</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

and from the second website (the one for which I am receiving the error):

```
<p class="txt-ctr-caps">Overnight<br><br></p>
            <p><img src="/images/wtf/medium/nra60.png" width="86" height="86" alt="Rain Likely Chance for Measurable Precipitation 60%" title="Rain Likely Chance for Measurable Precipitation 60%" /></p>
        <p>Rain<br>Likely<br></p>
            <p class="point-forecast-icons-low">Low: 3 &deg;C</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-ninth-first">
            <p class="txt-ctr-caps">Thursday<br><br></p>
            <p><img src="/images/wtf/medium/ra70.png" width="86" height="86" alt="Rain Likely Chance for Measurable Precipitation 70%" title="Rain Likely Chance for Measurable Precipitation 70%" /></p>
        <p>Rain<br>Likely<br></p>
            <p class="point-forecast-icons-high">High: 9 &deg;C</p>
    </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: please properly format your source code, have you look at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ its quite easy and fast to parse HTML, no point in re-inventing the wheel ...

Comment: I am new to this site, and I thought I formatted the source properly?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use xml parser? That makes it a million times easier to parse html than trying to hand code a search.

Comment: I have never used that before and already had similar code written, so I was just making a few changes. Though, if this proves too difficult I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you have provided complete code:
try this on

```
  def retrieveTemps(self) :
        filehandle = urllib.urlopen(self.url)
        lines = filehandle.read() # modified

        position1 = lines.rfind('#f2')
        if position1 > 0 :
                self.high0 = lines[position1:].split('&')[0].split('>')[1] # next line: high
                self.low0 = lines[position1+10:].split('&')[0].split('>')[1] # next line:low
        elif position1 < 0 :
                position1 = lines.rfind('>Overnight')
                if position1 > 0 :
                        self.high0 = lines[position1+9:].split('&')[0].split(':')[1] # next line: high
                        self.low0 = lines[position1+15:].split('&')[0].split(':')[1] # next line:low
```

Even that doesn'e help try to debug your code with basic print statements like what are having in your variables like line and lines when you are processing.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Once I make that change, I get the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: ok, lines = ?? in your program.
I think its the html output you paste

Comment: Sorry, guess I should have included all the code in my original post. I have updated the source code. Does that help?

Comment: @RahulGautam Almost! It outputs the number for both sites, the only problem is that it doesn't count down the number of lines I specify. It just goes to the first line with an '&' and '>' and uses that number every time.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks for the tip, I will do that next time.